# Can we hack a site that just stores the username as a session variable?

Tags: php, security, authentication

I've developed my website that checks if the user is registered and creates a session variable with the username. It's all that is stored as a session variable. If I want to protect my pages (so that only registered users may see them), I check if the session variable is set.
Is this secure?
Or can you give a more secure method?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generally, the Session is server side, but If I somehow get the Session ID I can just hijack it.

I'd recommend at least storing either the IP and maybe also the User-Agent, and in case of mismatch, invalidate the Session.

Comment: That's a nice way to add a layer or two of security. I would've thought that the platform that gives you the session does that automatically, but now that I think about it... probably not.

Comment: On the other hand, if you use SessionID it should be enough, and if you need more, you use sessions on SSL. On the IP Address, there are problems... "checks on IP address, for example, is foiled by AOL, who assign a new client IP on more or less every page request"

Comment: ...but don't forget that, in many cases, there is *not* a one-to-one correspondence of IP addresses to users and some of us use multiple browsers concurrently (sometimes on the same computer, sometimes on different boxes running different operating systems).

Comment: @Daniel: AOL assigns a new Client IP all the time? Whoa, that's crap. @Dave: Usually, if I use multiple browsers, I do so because I want to have two different sessions (I can always login twice), but I see your point. The OP did not give too much insight into his system though.

Answer (score 1):

**Basically, you are fine with storing whatever you want in Session.** The only caveats are:

- if you are not using secured connections (like SSL), the sessionId can be sniffed and hijacked. This is of no importance because the username and pass can also be hijacked, and you are subject to "man in the middle" attacks, etc. So basically, your system is fine and provides low security without SSL.
- In the articles on PHP they mention some concerns with shared hosting and session hijacking. I'm not sure if this is true, so I've posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487889). **Edit:** This concern seems to be real, so you'll have to use one of the workarounds for storing session (e.g., database) if you use PHP.

In general, though, most of the security concerns mentioned (including XSS attacks) are not with storing stuff in Session but rather general security concerns. Storing userid -- or some encrypted form of the same -- in Session is generally quite secure.

**Most importantly: if you were to use your own algorithm to generate a random cookie code for each user, that would no doubt have more security flaws (not being an expert) than the session-key generation algorithms of PHP, ASP.NET, Rails, whatever...**

I could find a more appropriate Bruce Schneier quote, but this one will do, "No one can duplicate the confidence that RSA offers after 20 years of cryptanalytic review.”

Comment: P.S. I'll be checking the answers provided to my other question by empirically trying it out...