# MVC EF keeps looking for userId which is costly

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, performance, entity-framework

Maybe it is some faulty logic in my code, but I have newest MVC EF Code first in C#. As I was looking at the sql profiler and expensive queries, I came to notice it is fetching a query like this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [UserId] FROM [Users] WHERE (UPPER([Email]) = @0)',
N'@0 nvarchar(71)',@0=N'myRegisteredEmail@someDomain.com'
```

Is this being cause by my frequent requests of `WebSecurity.CurrentUserId`? I thought it takes it once and it is all good? (but I see multiple calls in one page). Maybe each request to `WebSecurity.CurrentUserId` also causes the system to fetch the ID from database, keeping `Email` as the primary case of identification of the user (which I would prefer wasn't the case)?

I have queries where some foreign keys are users, but again, `Users` table's primary key is `UserId`, not email. Why would it keep trying to fetch it via the Email instead? So I scratched that thought too.

Thus I am unable to track down the reason it would fetch multiple times.

And finally, those queries take up to a quarter of a second. Add it a few times and the page loads quite slowly.

Comment: What's the code for WebSecurity.CurrentUserId? It may be calling the DB every single time.

Comment: @rikitikitik Well, I don't know, it is the value that comes from the system, I have no power over it.

Comment: If that's the case, you should probably store the value you get there to the Session then so you don't keep calling it. Without knowing what goes on in `CurrentUserId`, there's nothing much we can do about it.

Comment: @rikitikitik The last thing I need to know: is it secure to store CurrentUserId into the Session? For example, I will query to get the friends list for that user now using the new approach: the value from the session. Can it somehow be changed maliciously and thus gain access to all of that user's data or I can trust it to be as secure as it used to be by pulling the CurrentUserId every time I need it? If the security level doesn't decrease, please copy paste what you said in your last comment and I will gladly accept this as the right answer.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451543/how-safe-is-it-to-use-session-variables-asp-net-c-sharp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the latest MVC + EF, does this mean you are also using the newest identity framework Microsoft.AspNet.Identity?

If so, you can get your user's id like so:

```
User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

...where User is the IPrincipal on your Controller, HttpContext, etc. I am pretty sure you have to be using OWIN in place of FormsAuthentication in order to get this though.

This doesn't hit the database every time because the user id is stored as a claim; OWIN IPrincipals are ClaimsPrincipals.

Comment: You are right, I was not using asp.net.identity which seems to have given not one, but even more ideas on how to develop my upcoming project. I will soon test it with signalr, which is one the main tools of my app, hopefully it works with it too :) Thank you for this answer :)

Comment: Another option would be to write the userid to an encrypted cookie, which SignalR would have access to, since it comes in with the web request. However I have a strong feeling that if you are using OWIN + Microsoft.AspNet.Identity, you won't have to.

Comment: Thank you for response, yes I do hope that the next project that I will use the identity, I will be good with SignalR. However, I will definitely take a look at the encrypted cookies for my current one, since I will not be upgrading it to identity. Thanks again. You are really good at pointing to important things for me.

Comment: Yes, I finally managed to find time and tested and SignalR is doing fine with the new Identity system. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you've given, it looks like WebSecurity.CurrentUserId calls the database everytime. In order to minimize the database calls, you should store the value to a Session variable. Check out [how safe is it to use session variables - asp.net / c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451543/how-safe-is-it-to-use-session-variables-asp-net-c-sharp) to see previous discussions on the security of a Session.

If security is utmost in your application, such as in a banking web application, you can take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178201(v=vs.90).aspx to make Session security even more robust.

Comment: I tried session based approach and it was pretty helpful for that certain application, tho it doesn't work with signalr hubs :/

Comment: Technically you can get session to work with SignalR if you are not doing self-host, though it is neither straightforward nor recommended.