# how safe is it to use session variables? ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have this code in my Login page:

```
        Session["user"] = user.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", Session["user"]);
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

I saw this link [how safe is it to use session variables - asp.net / c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451543/how-safe-is-it-to-use-session-variables-asp-net-c-sharp)

and I want to know if I need to change this type of login.

my question is if its safe to use session and if its possible to steal a session from another user and enter to the website as that user or something like that.

I tried to use membership but I couldn't change the register so I moved to Session.

Comment: From what I know, session variables are stored on server per user, so it is safe there, unless the server is hacked

Comment: How hard is to get an access to the server?
and what is the best protected way to make a login page in asp.net?

Comment: Hacking a server should not be easy, and it is a job of System Administrator to protect on premises systems. Hacking a server could as easy as its weakest security point. If on premise system get hacked, a company will have most likely bigger problems than a single app. In the past I have developed my own custom login logic, I found over time that is much easier, better, more secure, and much faster to utilize out of the box membership/identity feature. Google it, you will find many articles helping you implement it

Comment: I tried to use membership but I couldn't edit the createuserwizard control..maybe you can help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38701388/how-to-add-values-to-database-with-createuserwizard-asp-net-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

Using session state to keep track of current login user is OK as long as you are on ***HTTPS***. Session variables are stored in Server Memory *(by default)*.

We all used the similar approach in Classics ASP and ASP.Net 1.0 *(before Membership in ASP.Net 2.0)*.

The main drawback is the **maintenance**. It is hard to maintain when the application has too many pages and too many users with different authorizations.

Comment: That is correct, I assumed the https by default, no important web app should transfer data over only http

Comment: Maybe the the user want to know why it isn't save to use it with HTTP :)

Answer (score 0):

As it has already been said, you should not have to worry about session security as long as you use https protocol and that your application server is safe.

But you should consider using Identity framework instead of the old Membership framework.
Since 2013 Identity is the new authentication .NET standard, allowing SSO, role provider, claims based authentication etc...

See http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity to understand why you should choose identity over membership)