# Using Session variable to protect from unauthorised access is safe or not

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, database

I am using the code below on admin.aspx page for not allowing unauthorised users.

```
if(Session[admin]! =null) 
{
   //my content here
} 
else
{
    response.redirect(login.aspx)
}
```

Is it safe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how safe is it to use session variables - asp.net / c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451543/how-safe-is-it-to-use-session-variables-asp-net-c-sharp)

Comment: you want to do more than just check if the Session object is null wouldn't you.. you need to compare it to something what will the rest of your code in the if block look like..?

Comment: Session is safe, but it would be better if you were checking the Identity / Role of user then performing this logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes It's safe but there are other approaches as well you can have a look into them from http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Simple-User-Login-Form-example-in-ASPNet.aspx or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879kf95c.aspx