# Why is this global list resetting to null when called by a GET Method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, get

I have a list that is declared globally

```
public class MyController : Controller
{

    private List<MyViewModel> wages = new List<MyViewModel>();
```

That is called in the Index GET method like so

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

if(list is empty)
{
   //Populate List
}
else if(list is NOT empty)
{
  //Display List Contents to User
}
else
{
  //Display 400 error (bad request)
}

}
```

Every time the above method is called from the browser, the list defaults to null, and has a zero count. As a result, all the data that is calculated in this method and stored in the list is recalculated every time the Index GET Method is called.

From my understanding, the GET method resets all runtime variables to their default state, before the code is executed, and the variables are repopulated with data, but I stand to be corrected. However, this shouldn't be the case considering that the list is not re-instantiated within the Index GET method.

Why is this list resetting to null every time this GET method is called? Surely, the data should be retained within the list given that the list was declared as a global variable, and not a method-wide variable, right?

Is there anything I can do to get around this? Is there anyway to try and persist the data at least so that it can be used elsewhere within the controller, and by extension, the MVC application?

Comment: HTTP is a stateless protocol, and a new Controller instance is created for each request. There are various ways to persist state such as hidden fields, cookies etc.

Comment: Where do you define `list`? Could you post your complete controller code?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay TBH I didn't know that a new controller instance is declared for each request. I always thought that the controller was concrete, and the views are dynamic. Would a Session variable work in this instance?

Comment: @SamanGholami I define list at the top of the controller. Please see the edit above to see where I declare the list.

Comment: Any kind of persistent or semi-persistent storage would help you - session, database, file, etc etc. You just need a bit of extra code to store the data in your chosen location and then retrieve it again each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of deliberation and research, I have resorted to using Session Variables to hold an instance of the list in question, and call said Session variable wherever I need to modify said list within a controller.

I would have used @Saman Gholami's answer, but during my experimentation, I found that the list continues to reset itself when the Index GET method is called, hence why I decided to switch over to Session variables. @Saman's answer was elegant, simple and to the point, but sadly didn't work in the way I wanted it to.

This plus the fact that, based on the links below, Session variables are predominantly loaded and utilized on the Server Side of the application, rather than the Client Side of the application.

Here is the links

[how safe is it to use session variables - asp.net / c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451543/how-safe-is-it-to-use-session-variables-asp-net-c-sharp)

https://forums.asp.net/t/1388630.aspx?Session+Variables+Secure+

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET MVC a `Controller` is created for every request by the ControllerFactory:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.defaultcontrollerfactory?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

You have to pay attention to ASP.NET life-cycle and if you want to define a list which shouldn't re-create for every request, put your definition line in `Global.asax` or `Startup.cs` as a `static` type:

```
public static List<MyViewModel> Wages = new List<MyViewModel>(); // in Startup.cs or Global.asax
```

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

   if(Startup.Wages is empty)
   {
      //Populate List
   }
   else if(Startup.Wages is NOT empty)
   {
     //Display List Contents to User
   }
   else
   {
     //Display 400 error (bad request)
   }

}
```

Comment: Derp. I completely overlooked the Global.asax route for solving this problem. Thanks for the post.